# Why does my Do-While loop keep breaking when I want it to return back to the Menu

Tags: c++, c++11

I want my do-while loop to keep repeating when I enter a number for a case. For Instance, If I wanted to Insert an element in an array I would enter 1, and then I would enter the element and index of where I want it to be inserted. It then should display the menu again, but for some reason, it just breaks out of the do-while loop?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct Array
{
    int *A;
    int size;
    int length;
};

void display(struct Array *arr)
{
    int i;
    printf("\nElements: ");
    for(i = 0; i < arr->length; i++)
        printf("%d ", arr->A[i]);
};

struct Array *mergeArrays(struct Array *array1, struct Array *array2)
{
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    int k = 0;

    struct Array *array3;

    int length = array1->length + array2->length;
    array3 = new Array[length];

    while(i < array1->length && j < array2->length)
    {
        if(array1->A[i] < array2->A[j])
        {   
            array3->A[k++] = array1->A[i++];
        }
        else
        {
            array3->A[k++] = array2->A[j++];
        }
    }

    for(; i < array1->length; i++)
        array3->A[k++] = array1->A[i];
    for(; j < array2->length; j++)
        array3->A[k++] = array2->A[j];

    array3->length = length;

    return array3;
};

struct Array *Union(struct Array *array1, struct Array *array2)
{
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    int k = 0;

    struct Array *array3;

    int length = array1->length + array2->length;
    array3 = new Array[length];

    while(i < array1->length && j < array2->length)
    {
        if(array1->A[i] < array2->A[j]) {   
            array3->A[k++] = array1->A[i++];
        }
        else if(array2->A[j] < array1->A[i]){
            array3->A[k++] = array2->A[j++];
        } else {
            array3->A[k++] = array1->A[i++];
            j++;
        }
    }

    for(; i < array1->length; i++)
        array3->A[k++] = array1->A[i];

    array3->length = k;
    array3->size = 10;

    return array3;
};

struct Array *Intersection(struct Array *array1, struct Array *array2)
{
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    int k = 0;

    struct Array *array3;

    int length = array1->length + array2->length;
    array3 = new Array[length];

    while(i < array1->length && j < array2->length)
    {
        if(array1->A[i] < array2->A[j]) {
            i++;
        } else if(array2->A[j] < array1->A[i]) {
            j++;
        } else {
            array3->A[k++] = array1->A[i++];
            j++;
        }
    }

    array3->length = k;
    array3->size = 10;

    return array3;
};

struct Array *Difference(struct Array *array1, struct Array *array2)
{
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    int k = 0;

    struct Array *array3;

    int length = array1->length + array2->length;
    array3 = new Array[length];

    while(i < array1->length && j < array2->length)
    {
        if(array1->A[i] < array2->A[j]) {   
            array3->A[k++] = array1->A[i++];
        }
        else if(array2->A[j] < array1->A[i]){
            j++;
        } else {
            i++;
            j++;
        }
    }

    for(; i < array1->length; i++)
        array3->A[k++] = array1->A[i];

    array3->length = k;
    array3->size = 10;

    return array3;
};

int Delete(struct Array *array1, int index)
{
    int x = 0;
    int i = 0;

    if(index >= 0 && index < array1->length)
    {
        x = array1->A[index];
        for(i = index; i < array1->length-1; i++)
            array1->A[i] = array1->A[i+1];
        array1->length--;
    }
    return x;
};

void Append(struct Array *array1, int value)
{  
    if(array1->length < array1->size)
        array1->A[array1->length++] = value;
};

void Insert(struct Array *array1, int index, int element)
{   
    int i;
    if(index >= 0 && index <= array1->length)
    {
        for(i = array1->length; i > index; i--)
            array1->A[i] = array1->A[i-1];

        array1->A[index] = element;
        array1->length++;
        
    }
}

bool Search(struct Array *array1, int element)
{
    for(size_t i{0}; i < array1->length; i++) {
        if(array1->A[i] == element)
            return true;
    }
    return false;
};

void Sum(struct Array array1)
{
    int arraySum = 0;

    for(int i{0}; i < array1.length; i++)
    {
        arraySum+=array1.A[i];
    }

    cout << arraySum << endl;
}


int main()
{
    int index;
    int x;
    int ch;

    struct Array array1;
    printf("Enter Size Of Array: ");
    scanf("%d", &array1.size);
    array1.A=(int *)malloc(array1.size*sizeof(int));

    do
    {
    printf("Display Menu\n");
    printf("1. Insert\n");
    printf("2. Delete\n");
    printf("3. Search\n");
    printf("4. Sum\n");
    printf("5. Display\n");
    printf("6. Exit \n");

    printf("Enter Your Choice: ");
    scanf("%d",&ch);

    switch(ch)
    {
        case 1: printf("Enter Element First And Then Index: ");
            scanf("%d%d", &x, &index);
            Insert(&array1,index, x);
            break;

        case 2: printf("Enter Index To Be Deleted: ");
            scanf("%d",&index);
            x = Delete(&array1, index);
            printf("Deleted Element is %d|n", x);
            break;

        case 3: printf("Enter Element To Be Searched: ");
            scanf("%d", x);
            x = Search(&array1, x);
            break;

        case 4: printf("Array Sum: ");
            Sum(array1);
            break;
        
        case 5: display(&array1);
    }
    } while(ch < 6);
      return 0;
}
```

Comment: You forgot to mention that it also segfaults

Comment: Try printing `array1->length` just before you do your insertion.

Comment: @smac89 Ah I know what I did wrong I think. I didn't set the length of the Array after I set the size.

Comment: Why are you using `malloc` in C++ and not `new` and `delete`? Why are you dynamically allocating instead of using `std::vector<struct Array>` or some similar STL container? One call to `puts(...)` is sufficient to display your entire menu (you can use a single `printf()` as well, but there are no conversions so `printf()` is not needed)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin I am following a tutorial on Algorithm and Data Structures and the teacher is using malloc for some reason and I do not know how to translate that into new. I would use a Vector, but he is teaching us what Arrays are.

Comment: Oh God, the teacher is using a lesson plan from 1991. What you are writing is C with a few `cin` and `cout` thrown in. When using `malloc` with C++, just remember you cannot MIX `malloc`, `calloc`, `realloc` & `free` with `new` & `delete`. They are like oil and water. You cannot use `malloc`, `calloc`, `realloc` with objects containing constructor (classes, structs, etc..) And point out to your teacher that you found that `malloc` hasn't been used in C++ since the early 90's and ask why are you learning it now?

Comment: Your code is full of undefined behavior due to you allocating `Array1` with `malloc` and then using `new` on the other arrays (e.g. `Array3`, etc..). Your `do .... while()` loop, other than lacking ALL validation of the user-inputs, and lacking the `break;` after `case 5:` -- should work as written.

Answer (score 0):

First, do NOT mix input with `std::cin` and C `scanf()`, that is just a recipe for disaster. Choose either C++ `iosteam` or C `stdio.h`, but not both. Regardless which you choose, it is up to you to ***validate every input*** by ***checking the return*** of the input function. In C++ you are checking the stream-state, in C you are validating the function return. In the case of a failure in both C and C++, character extraction from the input stream ceases when an error is encountered. It is up to you to handle the error and extract the offending characters from the input stream before attempting your next input (in C++ you must also `.clear()` the stream-state)

**Taking User-Input**

If you are using `scanf()` you will do:

```
        if (scanf ("%d",&ch) != 1) {    /* validate EVERY input */
            fputs ("  error: invalid integer input.\n", stderr);
            empty_stdin();              /* on invalid input, you must empty stdin */
            continue;
        }
```

Where the helper function `empty_stdin()` is written as:

```c
void empty_stdin (void)
{
    int c = getchar();
    
    while (c != '\n' && c != EOF)
        c = getchar();
}
```

(**note:** this applies to every input in your program... If you are using C input, consider reading all input into a fixed array with `fgets()` and parsing the needed values from the array with `sscanf()`. This eliminates the possibilities of offending characters left in the input stream in the case of a *matching-failure*.)

Using `iostream` in C++, you would do:

```cpp
        if (!(std::cin >> ch)) {    /* validate EVERY input, handle error */
            std::cerr << "  error: invalid integer input.\n";
            std::cin.clear();   /* clear failbit steam state */
            /* empty offendinding characters from stdin */
            std::cin.ignore (std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
            continue;
        }
```

Where `std::cin.ignore()` is provided for clearing offending characters with `std::numeric_limits` provided in `limits`.

**new or malloc()?**

You must be very careful using `malloc()` in C++. For example, allocation of a `stuct` with `malloc()` in C++ will fail. `malloc()` knows nothing about object constructors so if you allocate for `struct Array` with `malloc()` in C++, you end up with a partially constructed object. Use `new` and `delete` in C++ rather than `malloc()` and `free()` when allocating objects. You teacher should not be encouraging the use of `malloc()` in C++.

The only reason you can validly allocate for `array1.A` with `malloc()` is `A` is a plain old pointer-to `int`. There are no constructors associated with allocating storage for an `int`, so it is permissible (but not wise) to use `malloc()` in that case. The problem then becomes remembering what you allocated with `malloc()` and what you allocate with `new`, because `free()` and `delete` are not interchangeable.

**Your do { ... } while(); Loop**

On its face, there isn't any reason your do loop won't do what you are anticipating -- ***so long as every input is perfect***. However, one wrong character or one slip of the finger off a key and your whole house of fragile cards comes crashing down. What happens if the user slips reaching for `'4'` and taps `'r'` instead?  (really bad things). How do you handle the a `default:` case to generally handle errors if you exit for any valid integer greater than `5` (you can't).

By controlling the loop with `while (ch < 6);` you eliminate all error handling a default case can provide. If you want to exit on `6`, create a `case 6:` and use that to control exiting from the loop. Then you can loop `while (true);` or `do { ... } while (true);`

Whether you use C `stdio.h` or C++ `iostream` there is no reason to make Eight spearate function calls just to display your menu. You need one call to either `fputs()` or to `std::cout`. Why? During compilation, the compiler will join all adjacent string literals into a single string. So you can display your menu as:

```c
        fputs ("\nDisplay Menu\n"
               "  1. Insert\n"
               "  2. Delete\n"
               "  3. Search\n"
               "  4. Sum\n"
               "  5. Display\n"
               "  6. Exit \n\n"
               "Enter Your Choice: ", stdout);
```

or

```cpp
        std::cout << "\nDisplay Menu\n"
                     "  1. Insert\n"
                     "  2. Delete\n"
                     "  3. Search\n"
                     "  4. Sum\n"
                     "  5. Display\n"
                     "  6. Exit \n\n"
                     "Enter Your Choice: ";
```

(it's also a lot easier to read...)

**C++ Using C malloc() And stdio.h**

With those fixes in mind, and stripping out all unused functions, you can write your C++ code using `struct Array`, `malloc()` and `stdio.h` I/O functions, you could do:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct Array {
    int *A,
        size,
        length;
};

void display (struct Array *arr)
{
    int i;
    
    fputs ("\nElements: ", stdout);
    
    for(i = 0; i < arr->length; i++)
        printf (i ? " %d" : "%d", arr->A[i]);
    putchar ('\n');                             /* tidy up with newline */
}


int Delete (struct Array *array1, int index)
{
    int x = 0;
    int i = 0;

    if (index >= 0 && index < array1->length)
    {
        x = array1->A[index];
        for(i = index; i < array1->length-1; i++)
            array1->A[i] = array1->A[i+1];
        array1->length--;
    }
    
    return x;
}

void Insert(struct Array *array1, int index, int element)
{   
    int i;
    if(index >= 0 && index <= array1->length)
    {
        for(i = array1->length; i > index; i--)
            array1->A[i] = array1->A[i-1];

        array1->A[index] = element;
        array1->length++;
        
    }
}

bool Search(struct Array *array1, int element)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < array1->length; i++) {
        if(array1->A[i] == element)
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}

void Sum(struct Array array1)
{
    int arraySum = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < array1.length; i++)
    {
        arraySum+=array1.A[i];
    }

    printf ("%d\n", arraySum);
}

void empty_stdin (void)
{
    int c = getchar();
    
    while (c != '\n' && c != EOF)
        c = getchar();
}

int main (void)
{
    int index,
        x,
        ch;
    struct Array array1;
    
    fputs ("Enter Size Of Array: ", stdout);
    if (scanf("%d", &array1.size) != 1) {                   /* validate EVERY input */
        fputs ("error: invalid integer input.\n", stderr);
        return 1;
    }
    
    /* you cannot MIX malloc & new, you do not cast malloc in C, you do in C++ */
    array1.A = (int *)malloc(array1.size*sizeof(int));
    
    if (!array1.A) {    /* validate EVERY allocation using malloc */
        perror ("malloc-array1.A");
        return 1;
    }

    do
    {
        fputs ("\nDisplay Menu\n"
               "  1. Insert\n"
               "  2. Delete\n"
               "  3. Search\n"
               "  4. Sum\n"
               "  5. Display\n"
               "  6. Exit \n\n"
               "Enter Your Choice: ", stdout);
        
        if (scanf ("%d",&ch) != 1) {    /* validate EVERY input */
            fputs ("  error: invalid integer input.\n", stderr);
            empty_stdin();              /* on invalid input, you must empty stdin */
            continue;
        }
    
        switch(ch)
        {
            case 1: fputs ("Enter Element First And Then Index: ", stdout);
                if (scanf ("%d %d", &x, &index) != 2) {
                    fputs ("  error: invalid element or index.\n", stderr);
                    empty_stdin();
                    continue;
                }
                Insert (&array1, index, x);
                break;
    
            case 2: fputs ("Enter Index To Be Deleted: ", stdout);
                if (scanf ("%d", &index) != 1) {
                    fputs ("  error: invalid index to delete.\n", stderr);
                    empty_stdin();
                    continue;
                }
                x = Delete (&array1, index);
                printf ("Deleted Element is %d\n", x);
                break;
    
            case 3: printf ("Enter Element To Be Searched: ");
                if (scanf ("%d", &x) != 1) {
                    fputs ("  error: invalid search element.\n", stderr);
                    empty_stdin();
                    continue;
                }
                if (Search (&array1, x)) 
                    puts ("element found.");
                else
                    puts ("element not found.");
                break;
    
            case 4: fputs ("Array Sum: ", stdout);
                Sum (array1);
                break;
            
            case 5: display (&array1);
                break;
            
            case 6: puts ("\nend program");
                return 0;
                break;
            /* always provide a default case to catch invalid case requests */
            default: fputs ("  error: invalid selection.\n", stderr);
                break;
        }
    } while (1);
    
    free (array1.A);        /* don't forget to free the memory you allocate */
    
    return 0;
}
```

**Your Code Using C++ and std::vector<int>**

Your teacher is missing the point teaching you to use `stdio.h` and `malloc()` in C++. Yes, that was C++ in the early 90's, when C++ was a superset of C, but today, C++ is a language unto itself, without the need to rely on much of its C underpinnings. There is no reason to use a `struct Array` holding a pointer to `int*` and a `size` and `length`, [std::vector](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) provides all that functionality (and much, much more).

Using `std::vector<int>` to replace your `struct Array`, you can simplify and improve your program as follows:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <limits>

void display (std::vector<int>& arr)
{
    std::cout << "\nElements: ";
    
    for (int a : arr)
        std::cout << " " << a;
    std::cout.put ('\n');
}

void Delete (std::vector<int>& arr, size_t index)
{
    arr.erase (arr.begin() + index);
}

void Insert (std::vector<int>& arr, int element, size_t index)
{   
    if (index <= arr.size()) {
        arr.insert (arr.begin() + index, element);
    }
    else {
        std::cerr << "  error: index out of range, appending element.\n";
        arr.push_back (element);
    }
}

bool Search (std::vector<int>& arr, int element)
{
    for (int a : arr)
        if (a == element)
            return true;
    
    return false;
}

void Sum (std::vector<int>& arr)
{
    int arraySum = 0;

    for (int a : arr)
    {
        arraySum += a;
    }

    std::cout << arraySum << '\n';
}

int main (void)
{
    int ch = 0,
        x = 0;
    size_t ndx = 0;
    std::vector<int> array1{};
    
    do
    {
        std::cout << "\nDisplay Menu\n"
                     "  1. Insert\n"
                     "  2. Delete\n"
                     "  3. Search\n"
                     "  4. Sum\n"
                     "  5. Display\n"
                     "  6. Exit \n\n"
                     "Enter Your Choice: ";
        
        if (!(std::cin >> ch)) {    /* validate EVERY input, handle error */
            std::cerr << "  error: invalid integer input.\n";
            std::cin.clear();   /* clear failbit steam state */
            /* empty offendinding characters from stdin */
            std::cin.ignore (std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
            continue;
        }
    
        switch (ch)
        {
            case 1: std::cout << "Enter Element and index: ";
                /* validate EVERY input, handle error */
                if (!(std::cin >> x >> ndx)) {
                    std::cerr << "  error: invalid input for insert.\n";
                    std::cin.clear();   /* clear failbit steam state */
                    /* empty offendinding characters from stdin */
                    std::cin.ignore (std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
                    continue;
                }
                Insert (array1, x, ndx);
                break;
    
            case 2: std::cout << "Enter Index To Be Deleted: ";
                if (!(std::cin >> ndx)) {  /* validate EVERY input, handle error */
                    std::cerr << "  error: invalid index input to delete.\n";
                    std::cin.clear();   /* clear failbit steam state */
                    /* empty offendinding characters from stdin */
                    std::cin.ignore (std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
                    continue;
                }
                if (ndx < array1.size()) {
                    x = array1[ndx];                /* index < size */
                    std::cout << "Deleted Element is " << x << '\n';
                    Delete (array1, ndx);
                }
                else {  /* ndx not a valid index */
                    std::cerr << "  error: invalid index.\n";
                }
                break;
    
            case 3: std::cout << "Enter Element To Be Searched: ";
                if (!(std::cin >> x)) {    /* validate EVERY input, handle error */
                    std::cerr << "  error: invalid integer input to search.\n";
                    std::cin.clear();   /* clear failbit steam state */
                    /* empty offendinding characters from stdin */
                    std::cin.ignore (std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
                    continue;
                }
                if (Search (array1, x)) 
                    std::cout << "element found.\n";
                else
                    std::cout << "element not found.\n";
                break;
    
            case 4: std::cout << "Array Sum: ";
                Sum (array1);
                break;
            
            case 5: display (array1);
                break;
            
            case 6: std::cout << "\nend program\n";
                return 0;
                break;
            /* always provide a default case to catch invalid case requests */
            default: std::cerr << "  error: invalid selection.\n";
                break;
        }
    } while (true);
}
```

There are a few other changes incorporated and noted in the comments, but basically, other than learning how things were done in the past, you want to concentrate your C++ learning on how C++ is used today. Otherwise, learning C would have covered the entirety of what you posted in your question.

Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.